# Why HttpResponse always return 404 status code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to send request to `http://localhost/apptfg/get_biography_group?nombre_grupo=fondoflamenco` which is a php based webservice that access to mysql database and retrieve information about the group but I always get a 404 not found when I execute the application in my windows phone 8 device, however when I debug the url in fiddler I get the right result which must be `{"success":1,"group":[{"nombre_grupo":"fondoflamenco","anyo_creacion":"2006","descripcion":"Fondo Flamenco Flamenco is a group formed by three young Sevillian. Astola Alejandro Soto, Antonio Sanchez and Rafael Ruda M.R","musicos":"Rafael Ruda,Antonio Manuel Rios,"}]}`
this is the HttpClient code I use in my application:

```
       public async Task<string> makeHttpRequest(string group_name)
    {
        var resultstring = String.Empty;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/html");

        try
        {
            resultstring = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/apptfg/get_group_biography.php?nombre_grupo=" + group_name));
            client.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        }
        return resultstring;
    }
```

Comment: Use exp.ToString in catch and post the message here

Comment: The two URLs are different. First you write http://localhost/apptfg/get_biography_group, but in your code it is http://localhost/apptfg/get_group_biography.php.

Comment: the second one is the right url. Here is the exp.ToString() result: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 ().